# In two-panel fragment Activity, how to make one fragment take over full screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments

On tablets, one of my activities has a split screen - a list in the left panel, and a map in the right.

If a user wants to maximize the map fragment, is it better to set the left fragment to a `0dp` width, or set `android:visibility="gone"`? If the latter, will it's lifecycle events still be called? (i.e. If the user then exits the application, and re-enters later.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it better to set the left fragment to a 0dp width, or set android:visibility="gone"?

In terms of UI load, there is very little difference between these two. Regardless of the option you choose, the left fragment would still be inflated (even though it's not visible to the user). **So basically, it's your choice.** My preference is usually to alter the visibility (gone/visible) but then, that's just a personal preference.

> If the latter, will it's lifecycle events still be called?

**Yes.** The visibility of a view does not affect/determine its lifecycle.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its lifecycle events will be triggered. Because fragment lifecycle does not depend on the UI but on the connection to the fragmentManager of an activity.